# OneSignal Error: "app_id not found"

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework, onesignal

I am getting this error whenever I try to post a notification with OneSignaL:

```
app_id not found. You may be missing a Content-Type: application/json header
```

Here is my code:

```
function notifyUser(id, msg) {
    var notificationObj = { contents: {en: msg},
                            include_player_ids: [id],
                            'Content-Type': 'application/json' };
    window.plugins.OneSignal.postNotification(notificationObj,
      function(successResponse) {
        console.log("Notification Post Success:", successResponse);
      },
      function (failedResponse) {
        console.log("Notification Post Failed: ", failedResponse);
        alert("Notification Post Failed:\n" + JSON.stringify(failedResponse));
      }
    );
};
```

I added the 'Content-Type' part because that's what the error says to do but I still get the same error.  This is the sample code striaght from their [docs](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/cordova-sdk#section--postnotification-) - They don't even include the Content-Type:

```
window.plugins.OneSignal.getIds(function(ids) {
  var notificationObj = { contents: {en: "message body"},
                          include_player_ids: [ids.userId]};
  window.plugins.OneSignal.postNotification(notificationObj,
    function(successResponse) {
      console.log("Notification Post Success:", successResponse);
    },
    function (failedResponse) {
      console.log("Notification Post Failed: ", failedResponse);
      alert("Notification Post Failed:\n" + JSON.stringify(failedResponse));
    }
  );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I commented out the setup portion of my OneSignal while I was running my tests.

Answer (score -1):

I was sending non-utf8 characters, and this was the problem. Check your encodings.